# Weird object properties that can not be referred

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I use React Material-UI for my project. I put many components in render method. Then weird things happened. Some components can not be referred by 'this.refs.REFNAME'. And then I checked 'this.refs' object, it shows as the pic below:

[image]

As you can see, only some of the components, which can be referred, are showed on the first line. I don't understand why. Can anyone explain it to me? Thanks lot.

Update: Thanks to James, I get it that the first line should be the status of 'this.refs' at that moment. But still, why some of the components are not in the refs object?

Here's the relevant part of code:

```js
  render(){
    return <div>
      <Table ref='fromform'>
        <TableHeader>
          <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn tooltip='The ID'>No.</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn tooltip='The Name'>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn tooltip='The Status'>Notes</TableHeaderColumn>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody ref='fromformb'>
          {playerList.map(function(player, index){
              return <TableRow onTouchTap={this._onShowInfo.bind(this, index)} key={'row' + index}>
                <TableRowColumn>{index + 1}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{player.name}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{player.notes}</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>;
          }.bind(this))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
      <Dialog
        title='Player Info'
        ref='playerInfoDialog'>
        <form role='form' ref='fromfo'>
          <div className='form-group' ref='frowwmformb'>
            <TextField type='text' hintText='Player Name' ref='txtName' fullWidth={true} />
            <TextField type='text' hintText='Notes' ref='txtNotes' fullWidth={true} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </Dialog>
      <MainButtonGroup page='players' />
      <Spinner />
    </div>;
  }
  
  _onShowInfo(index){
    var player = playerList[index];
    console.log(this.refs);
    this.refs.playerInfoDialog.show();
    this.refs.txtName.setValue(player.name);
    this.refs.txtNotes.setValue(player.notes);
  }
}
```

What I want to do with this code is to generate rows in a table with player list, and when I tap a row, a dialog shows up with the data of the row.

But the two 'TextField's with refs of 'txtName' and 'txtNotes' can't be referred(as on the last 2 lines, produce errors). The pic above is produced by 'console.log' in '_onShowInfo' method.
I added some 'ref's with random names just to test.

Comment: Note that the small blue "i" is an indication that the object will be re-evaluated when you expand the view.  It may be when initially logged, it only had `fromformb`, `fromform` and `playerInfoDialog`, then you have some other asynchronous code that's causing the other properties to become available between the time of you logging it and expanding the object.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Change _onShowInfo as below:

```
_onShowInfo(tid){
  var player = playerList[index];
  this.refs.playerInfoDialog.show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(this.refs);
    this.refs.name.setValue(player.name);
    this.refs.notes.setValue(player.notes);
  }.bind(this), 0);
}
```

But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when the dialog is hidden, its children are not mounted yet. So the refs defined in the children are not set yet.

You see them in the console, though, as Chrome automatically updates it when it gets set because there is referential equality between the old `this.refs` and the new one. If you want to log the refs at a given point in time and make sure it is not updated by Chrome, you could do : `console.log({ ...this.refs })`

Another approach would be to hold a reference to the selected player in your component's state. Then you would have:

```
_onShowInfo(tid){
    var player = playerList[index];
    this.setState({selectedPlayer: player});
}
```

and

```
<Dialog
  title='Player Info'
  open={ !!this.state.selectedPlayer }
>
  <form role='form'>
    <div className='form-group'>
      <TextField type='text' hintText='Player Name' defaultValue={ this.state.player.name} fullWidth={true} />
    </div>
  </form>
</Dialog>
```